# Can I use a JWT from cognito (IdP is Salesforce with oidc) to query Salesforce API?

Tags: jwt, salesforce, amazon-cognito, openid-connect

So, after a lot of Googling and tests on my side, I cannot figure out if this is even possible (kind of a newbie here with oidc + cognito + salesforce).

I have a need to authenticate my users via SSO with Salesforce as an identity provider. Then, I need to query for that specific user's information via Salesforce API. I want to avoid an extra oauth flow if possible since theoretically I have my users logged in already.

The scenario is:

1. I have configured Cognito with Salesforce as my identity provider via Open ID Connect.
2. I managed to perform the auth flow correctly and I end with a code that I can exchange for an `id_token`, `access_token` and a `refresh_token` from cognito's `/oauth2/token` endpoint.
3. Now the question is IF I can use the JWT tokens I got from cognito to query Salesforce API.

I can elaborate and provide sample configuration if needed. Thanks a lot for any help on this :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In OAuth, the data owner hosts an Authorization Server / token issuer alongside its APIs:

- So Salesforce access tokens must be used to get Salesforce data
- Similarly a client must use access tokens from your Cognito instance to get data from your own APIs

**EMBEDDED TOKEN PATTERN**

This is the design pattern you need, and it is explained in [this Curity article](https://curity.io/resources/learn/token-sharing/#embedding-a-token). When Cognito federates to Salesforce, it will complete a code flow for the user and get Salesforce tokens.

It should then be possible to include the Salesforce access token as a claim in the Cognito access token. Your APIs can extract it later on, then forward it to Salesforce on behalf of the user.

**COGNITO CAPABILITIES?**

Unfortunately not all Authorization Servers have this level of extensibility, so I doubt that Cognito supports this, but it is worth investigating. It is not an uncommon requirement though, and Cognito does allow you to get `Identity Pool` tokens to represent user specific AWS resources in a similar way.

Comment: Thanks a lot for that! At least now I know what I am talking about hehe. Unfortunately, I cannot find anywhere how to make the embedded token happen between Cognito and Salesforce. As you said, it might not be supported. But I'll keep investigating. 
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

After some research, I think I found the way (not sure if it is the best, but it works).

This is the process:

1. When creating the user pool, make sure you declare 2 custom attributes: `access_token` and `refresh_token`.
2. Complete the setup process.
3. In the attribute mapping section, map those custom attributes to the ones you want to extract from your Idp (in my case, `access_token` is the one I need)

So, it will look like this:

[image: Cognito attribute mapping configuration]

That attaches the Salesforce `access_token` to my JWT `id_token` :)

Comment: Nice - I didn't know you could do that. Cognito seems a little non-standard in its token customization. The standard thing is to customize access tokens, and for APIs to use scopes and claims to authorize requests. I would send the access token to your APIs in the HTTP Authorization Header, for a standard architecture. Then maybe dig out the Salesforce token and send that in a secondary header.